# Laravel NotFoundHttpException No query results for model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have error **NotFoundHttpException No query results for model [App\ThreadForum]**

My **web.php** :

```
Route::get('/threads','ThreadForumController@index');
Route::post('/threads','ThreadForumController@store');
Route::get('/threads/create','ThreadForumController@create');
Route::get('/threads/{thread}','ThreadForumController@show')->name('threads.show');
```

My **model**:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ThreadForum extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','title','body'
    ];

    public  function  path(){
        return route('threads.show',$this->id);
    }
    public function  replies(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Reply');
    }

    public function creator(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }

    public  function  addReply($reply){
        $this->replies()->create($reply);

    }
}
```

My **controller**:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\ThreadForum;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ThreadForumController extends Controller
{
    public function  __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->only('store');
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $threads = ThreadForum::all();
        return view('threads.index', compact('threads'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('threads.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        dd('store');
        /*$thread = ThreadForum::create([
            'user_id'=>auth()->id(),
            'title'=>$request['title'],
            'body'=>$request['body']
        ]);
        redirect($thread->path());*/
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\ThreadForum  $threadForum
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(ThreadForum $thread)
    {
        return view('threads.show',compact('thread'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\ThreadForum  $threadForum
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(ThreadForum $threadForum)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\ThreadForum  $threadForum
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, ThreadForum $threadForum)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\ThreadForum  $threadForum
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(ThreadForum $threadForum)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

All functions work well, but when I run post('/threads') for store new record  I get error.
I tried use dd('store') for debugging, but I dont see this text, only error.
How can I fix it? 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you perhaps turned on route cache and wrote the route afterwards? If that is the case you might want to run `php artisan route:clear` to bust the cache.

Comment: Show  your view, where you have the post form

Comment: what is the URL the request is going to that you are getting this error? are those all the routes with that prefix?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment, but to dump you have to use `dd($request)` not `dd($store)`

EDIT: I think that problem is in show method. You use  compact, but there's no any variable above it. So you cannot pass anything to view.

Comment: It's a string litteral, so no problem

Comment: I use this for show method:`Route::get('/threads/{thread}','ThreadForumController@show')->name('threads.show');` , it works well

Comment: all methods works, but I cannot  run `Route::post('/threads','ThreadForumController@store');`

Comment: `$thread` is in the method signature, it is parameter ... that is a variable

Comment: clear your routes and try again. at the moment the route with post is not found and that is why it goes to the route with get